# Spacewalk reboot the server after patch installed

Tags: centos, ansible, spacewalk

I am using Spacewalk release 2.9 to manage my CentOS Linux server. using below `spacecmd` command to push the new packages. I want to reboot the server once all the packages are installed on the machine. I am unsure how to monitor package upgrade and issue the reboot command. Any recommendations to achieve this? I would like to use Ansible playbook to do this reboot.

```
spacecmd  system_upgradepackage  <hostname> '*' -y
```

Thanks
SR

Comment: Above `spacecmd` command invokes the packages to be pushed, it won't wait until task completed, we need to wait patches pushed and reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible can reboot the server without using `spacecmd`, using the `reboot` command.

```
- name: Upgrading via spacewalk
  shell: spacecmd  system_upgradepackage  <hostname> '*' -y
- name: Reboot after upgrades
  shell: reboot
  async: 0
  poll: 0
- name: Waiting for host to come up
  local_action: wait_for host={{ ansible_ssh_host }} state=started
```

Adapted from: https://www.linux.com/tutorials/ansible-reboot-server-play-book-and-wait-it-come-back

Comment: we need to check patches pushed, before invoking os reboot. otherwise system will reboot in middle of patching.

Comment: we need to wait until this command output comes zero `spacecmd system_listupgrades <hostname> |wc -l` Is it possible to check with ansible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `spacecmd`, but you can use the `wait_for` module to monitor the PID.

From docs:

```
- name: Wait until the process is finished and PID was destroyed
  wait_for:
    path: /proc/3466/status
    state: absent
```

Comment: spacecmd will be running from control host, we can check the  PID status to check the patch push status.

Comment: so we can wait until the PID gets exited in localhost